# Query for non empty string property?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is there any way to query Datastore for entities where a specific property should not be the empty string?

I'm not referring to missing properties. I really mean non empty strings.

Answer (score 5):

By using [filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Filters) you can specify that value of the property is greater than "" (empty string). I don't use Go so I can't guarantee if it'll work but in other languages this trick usually works...

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Example").Filter("Property >", "")
```